# How do I avoid data formatting when replacing text VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a new user!
I've been using VBA for a while but I need your help now.

I wrote a Macro and, among many things, it should find and replace text in a column.
Originally, the column have text written this way: "24.12.2019".
What I try to do is to find "." and replace it with "/".

By doing so, however, VBA tries to convert it into a date (ENG format mm/dd/yyyy).
Obviously, when the day is greater then 12, it keeps it as a text.

Well, I would like to keep the format as "dd/mm/yyyy" and avoid VBA to convert the range.

(`"SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False"` don't work out)

Comment: You could add an `'` in front of the string to keep it as text

Comment: Thanks for answering!
Believe me I tried but it didn’t work

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25348810) to provide the relevant part of your code

Comment: Maybe a more complete example of your code, would help us answer your question .

Comment: So, you like to avoid Excel guessing what data type you introduce and **always be text**? If yes, what column do you like to behave as requested? If not, please better describe what you need...

Comment: I will as soon as possible, thank you

Comment: What column would you like to always remain formatted as text?

Comment: Hi FaneDuru. Yes, if it could work. Originally the column is formatted as text since there are dots in the date. I think when the code does the replacement, VBA guesses those cells are dates. Obviously, the standard is “mm/dd/yyyy” but I would like to avoid it. I tried by combining the cells with ‘ before doing the replacement but it didn’t work.

Comment: Would you prefer a dd/mm/yy date format rather than text with the "/"? I have code already written to achieve this, you would just need to apply it to yours.

Comment: Yes, it would be the optimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're aiming to have excel recognize the data as a date but in a DD/MM/YY format, below is how you would do it. Just change the selection `Columns("A:A")` part and the destination `Range("A1")

```
Columns("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
    Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, _
    Comma:=False, _
    Space:=False, _
    Other:=False, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(1, 4), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy;@" ' or "dd\/mm\/yy;@" depending on region
```

Comment: Thank you Mark, I’m going to try asap and let you know.

Comment: @LucaA88 to clarify this will not keep the column as text. It will convert it to a dd/mm/yy date format.

Comment: And this is how it *should* be done. Dates are not text. Formatting/treating dates as text is how you get headaches.

Comment: But `NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy;@"` will format the date according to Regional Settings. If the date is shown in format '"dd.mm.yy"`, applying of this format will be shown in the same way, I think. And I do not know if this is what he want. Anyhow, he will clarify the issue after making tests as he announced...

Comment: @FaneDuru if it's an issue, I'll add a walk-through on how to get the format code and modify the code accordingly.

Comment: Range.NumberFormat = "dd\/mm\/yy;@"

Comment: @Guest: This format reverses ''mm'' with "dd", in cases of day being < 12, for Regional Settings default data as "dd.mm.yy", like it look to be  LucaA88's case... Keeping everything as Text, offers the possibility to use the date like `DateValue(ActiveCell.Value)` as (I understood) he needs to be interpreted. But, it looks that 'asap' for him can take longer then expected...

Comment: I’m not in office all day long and I’ve got a Macbook at home.. that’s why I couldn’t try it out “soon” as you expected. However, Mark’s solutions works pretty well. I’m 100% satisfied! Thank you all for your help, great community!

Answer (score 0):

In order to Oblige Excel to keep text in your column, you must runt this piece of code before replacing existing text:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
   Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your sheet
   sh.Range("E:E").TextToColumns Destination:=sh.Range("E1"), FieldInfo:=Array(1, 2)
```

Comment: Thank you FaneDuru, I’m going to try asap and let you know.

Comment: Take care **to have some values in the cells you want later to replace the content** and remained formatted as text, independent of your input...